# Rails not seeing .tooltip method even with jQuery included

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a new Rails project and trying to integrate a theme. However, the theme is using `.tooltip` in its `.js` file, and Rails is giving me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Here is my `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require activestorage
//= require theme/inspinia.js
//= require theme/metisMenu.js
//= require theme/jquery.slimscroll.min.js
```

which looks very identical to a previous Rails app that I have.

Here's the `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Jquery
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Used for server-side processing of datatables.
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'
```

I read in other posts here that this is usually caused by jquery being called multiple times, but I'm unable to determine where this is happening at. If I try to render a blank page, I still get the error, so I'm not sure it's anything in the HTML causing it. I must be missing something or have something in the wrong order.

If I remove `theme/inspinia.js` from the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, then it no longer appears. However, I still get the error if I call it manually. This is where it's being called in the `app/assets/javascripts/theme/inspinia.js` file:

```
$('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
    selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
    container: "body"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't load the jquery ui in your project.
Load jquery-ui before the inspina.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui 
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require activestorage
//= require theme/inspinia.js
//= require theme/metisMenu.js
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up including bootstrap-sprockets and this solved the issue. Haven't tried your solution but I upvoted it. Much appreciated again!